# Where can I get sqlcmd.exe for Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sqlcmd

I am looking to install this on a 64 bit system in order to test SQL queries against an ODBC source. The current links are Microsoft are too new. Does anyone know where I can download it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLCMD should come with Management Studio http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593 However there's no reason why you couldn't use a newer version of SQLCMD to connect to an older database.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2008 R2, you want to download the files from what is called the Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Feature Pack. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978

From there, you are going to need 2 programs 
 "Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Native Client" X64 Package (sqlncli.msi)  and "Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Command Line Utilities"  X64 Package (SqlCmdLnUtils.msi) in either 32 bit or 64 bit form depending on where you are installing it. Most servers are 64 bit so if doubt, choose that version first.
Install the native client first and command line utilities second.